# Font used in Seth Thomas logo

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me identify the font used in the Seth Thomas logo? I recon the S and the T has been subject to some modifications, but the rest of the letters seem to be a spesific typeface?

[image]

Thanks so much!
Simen.

Comment: Can you tell us which [identifcation services](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) you've tried so that there is no doubling up on effort?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to turn up the exact font, but most logos are not an unaltered font taken exactly the way it was designed. That said I would be surprised that this font is what Seth Thomas Clocks used (they were incorporated in 1853), what seems more likely is that someone designed a digital font off of the logo or another script to make this one. That said, this font will get you close: [Sheer Beauty](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Sheer+Beauty/)

There are several things you will need to do in order to get the logo perfect though. First of all there is a 10˚ sheer on it to get the angle right.

[image: Comparison 1]

Next you will notice that the original has closer letter spacing than Sheer Beauty, therefore you will need to adjust that and fix the ligatures.

[image: Comparison 2]

Lastly, There are at least eight other issues with the font that will need to be added or adjusted to be perfect.

[image: Comparison 3]

All in all it might be just as easy to get a piece of tracing paper and draw it.
Hope that helps!

Comment: JohnB: I used WhatTheFont but I could not get a clear result.

Comment: Nichooco: Tank you som much for your good, thorough reply!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps with what you're doing.